# swift call oc class getter method in oc project

Tags: ios, swift

oc project；

I has class like this

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
@property(noatomic,getter=getNode)id node;
@end
```

and in swift file

```
var node =  MyObject().getNode
```

and getNode method not found ?

anyone helps

Comment: Check the bridge file (the `YourProject-Swift.h`) is it appears.

Comment: yes, I found the file at DeriverdData dir